# How do I order the results of a 1 to many relationship

Tags: orm, propel

I'm using Propel 1.5.7 and can't figure out the right way to order the results of a `get[Related]s()` call.

**e.g.**

Say, an `Author` has many `Books`:

```
 $leo = AuthorQuery::create()->findByLastName("Tolstoy");
 $books = $leo->getBooks();
```

And, books have a `PublishDate` column.

How do I get `$books` to be sorted by `PublishDate`?  Can I pass something to `getBooks()` to make this happen.  I can't find any mention of it in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my knowledge, this is the only way to sort leo's books by publication date.

You can however make it prettier by using the BookQuery class to create your criteria (as a BookQuery is indirectly a Criteria) :

```
$criteria = BookQuery::create()->orderByPublishDate();
$books = $leo->getBooks($criteria);
```

Using this method, you'll also be able to use the methods defined in your BookQuery class and, let's imagine, only retrieve five leo's books published by a given author.

```
$criteria = BookQuery::create()
    ->filterByGenre('Fiction');
    ->limit(5);
    ->orderByPublishDate();
$books = $leo->getBooks($criteria);
```

Comment: Perfect, it even works in one line: `$books = $leo->getBooks(BookQuery::create()->orderByPublishDate());`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not happy with this answer, but it worked.

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(BookPeer::PUBLISH_DATE);
$books = $leo->getBooks($c);
```

Create a new `Criteria`, add the order by and pass it to `get[Related]s()`.